# how to create 3 columns in HTML+CSS and group 2 div elements in the third column

Tags: html, css

I've an issue with creating 3 columns in HTML+CSS

This is the html code:

```
<div class="views-field-field-pdf-fid"></div>                
<div class="views-field-field-content-value"></div>
<div class="views-field-field-image-fid"></div>
<div class="views-field-title"></div>
<div class="views-field-field-date-value"></div>
```

What I want is 3 columns:

```
1st column: title, date-value
2nd column: image-fid
3rd column: content-value, pdf-fid
```

So far, I've tried to add `float:right` property to `content-value, pdf-fid and image-fid`. Unfortunately I cannot keep content-value and pdf-fid on the same column.

ps. I can swap the divs in the html code but not grouping them using parent divs.
thanks

Comment: why can't you group them in parent divs?  That's my solution to this layout.

Comment: You keep mentioning columns. Why don't you use a table? If you don't wanna use a table, why are you apposed to grouping them with a parent div?

Comment: @MattoTodd - you beat me to it. Nice.

Comment: With the conditions specified, it sounds like a riddle / homework assignment :-)

Comment: @Surreal Dreams @MattoTodd @Dutchie432 @jeroen So, does the riddle have a solution ? Or there is no way to do it without creating a parent div or table ?

Comment: @Patrick I think it depends on the heights of the divs, are they completely random or can you already say that for example `title` is smaller than `content`?

Comment: @jeroen title, Date-value and pdf-fid are 1 line. Content 2 or 3. All the columns have the same height in the end.

Comment: I now see you wrote it is possible in one of the answers. Could you provide me the exact css code, because I cannot find the right solution

Comment: @Patrick I just added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to order the divs and use a combination of `float:left` / `float:right` and `clear:left` / `clear:right`. And perhaps use absolute positioning for the middle column.

Something like this should work if `title` is always smaller than `content`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width: 32%;
                margin: 0 1% 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="views-field-field-content-value" style="background-color: #000; height: 300px; float: right;"></div>  
    <div class="views-field-title" style="background-color: #333; height: 100px; float: left;"></div>             
    <div class="views-field-field-image-fid" style="background-color: #666; height: 400px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 33%;"></div>
    <div class="views-field-field-date-value" style="background-color: #ccc; height: 100px; float:left; clear: left;"></div>
    <div class="views-field-field-pdf-fid" style="background-color: #999; height: 100px; float: right; clear: right;"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a table?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="views-field-title"></div>
    <div class="views-field-field-date-value"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="views-field-field-image-fid"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="views-field-field-content-value"></div>
    <div class="views-field-field-pdf-fid"></div>                
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess I should have put my suggestion as an answer (+1)

Comment: I cannot create a table for the same reason I cannot create a parent div. I'm using a CMS (Drupal - Views) and adding items to a list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want equal width for all three columns but here's a start for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xj6UC/

CSS:

```
#one {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#two {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#three {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="three">
    <div class="views-field-field-pdf-fid">pdf</div>                
    <div class="views-field-field-content-value">content value</div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <div class="views-field-field-image-fid">image</div>
</div>
<div id="one">
    <div class="views-field-title">title</div>
    <div class="views-field-field-date-value">date value</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP said "but not grouping them using parent divs"

Comment: @Patrick -Why can't you use parent Div's? is jeroen right, are we solving your homework assignment?

Comment: @MattoTodd Because I'm using Drupal, Views module to add the fields, and there is no such functionality

Comment: So why can't you use parent divs again?